# Beetle (?) on Acacia (Senegalia) greggii?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I was working on my botany skills and took a photo of *Acacia (Senegalia) greggii*.  When I reviewed the photos, I saw a beetle (I think it's a bettle) that I had not noticed in the field.  I'd say its body is about 2 cm long.  This plant was growing in a dry wash in Phoenix Arizona USA, and the flowers on the plant were just maturing.  Observed around 9 am and the temperature was about 75-80 F. What species is this insect?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the [Longhorn beetle](http://www.arizonensis.org/sonoran/fieldguide/arthropoda/schizax_senex.html) (*Schizax senex*), possibly a female, but it is hard to judge the length of the antennae. This beetle has long antennae (hence the longhorn name), with the male having antennae that are nearly twice as long as the female. S. senex is the only species of the genus.

They are hirsute with a pale margin to the wing cases. The species was [described in 1873 by](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/9055644#page/688/mode/1up) LeConte, with the description being rather wonderful (in my opinion):

> Niger opacicus, pube breve minus subtili cinerea vestitus, prothorace fortus, elytrus subtilius punctatus, his marginae suturali laterali apicali et scutello fulvo-pubescentibus

My very rough translation - better Latin scholars please fix:

> Black opaque, hair short with subtle grey arrangement, prothorax strong, wing cases with subtle dots, and the join margins and edges pointed and scutes fawn-coloured and very hairy.

Note that I found this with a very quick google of "beetles arizona" and scanning through the linked arizonensis beetles page, which was at the top of the links provided by google. I am not from the USA or in the USA, so please anyone with a better identification, feel free to chime in.

Comment: Looks like a very good match, thanks!